# using thread in JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

i have a mainFrame that contains panel. i want in this panel a thread that changes label image as long as the application is running...

when i created the panel that implements runnable, and then created an instance of this panel in the mainframe the application goes into infinite loop... my code as follows:

```
public mainFrame()
{
     BanerPanel baner = new BanerPanel();
     baner.run();
}

public class Banner_Panel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public Banner_Panel() {
        initComponents();
        imgPath = 2;
        imgLbl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Photos/banner_4-01.png")));
        add(imgLbl);
        //run();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true)
        {
            try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                switch(imgPath)
                {
                    case 1:
                        imgLbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Photos/banner_4-01.png")));
                        imgPath = 2;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        imgLbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Photos/banner_1-01.png")));
                        imgPath = 3;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        imgLbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Photos/banner_2-01.png")));
                        imgPath = 4;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        imgLbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Photos/banner_3-01.png")));    
                        imgPath = 1;
                        break;
                }

            }
            } catch (InterruptedException iex) {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user1329572 thats right, works for me but ImageIcon must be flush()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Don't call `JLabel#setIcon(...)` in a background thread as this must be called on the Swing event thread or EDT. Instead, why not simply us a Swing Timer?
- Also, there's no need to continually read in the image from the disk.  Instead, read the images in once and place the ImageIcons in an array or `ArrayList<ImageIcon>` and simply iterate through the icons in your Swing Timer.
- Your code actually doesn't use a background thread as you're calling `run()` directly on your Runnable object which isn't doing any threading at all. Please read the [threading tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) to see how to use Runnables and Threads (hint you call `start()` on the Thread).

For example

```
// LABEL_SWAP_TIMER_DELAY a constant int = 3000
javax.swing.Timer myTimer = new javax.swing.Timer(LABEL_SWAP_TIMER_DELAY, 
      new ActionListener(){
  private int timerCounter = 0;

  actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // iconArray is an array of ImageIcons that holds your four icons.
    imgLbl.setIcon(iconArray[timerCounter]);
    timerCounter++;
    timerCounter %= iconArray.length;
  }
});
myTimer.start();
```

For more, please check out the [Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: i duno why i'm always taking -1 in votes... is that because my late response or what? actually i check the answers after a while..

Comment: @BDeveloper: I can't answer for why others have done that, and in particular without leaving a comment. I've up-voted your question to at the least nullify the down-vote.